# Why does the map function, in Java Spark, need an Encoder? It looks sometimes superfluous. Do I have a way asking map function not to use any encoder?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have this business object:

```java
public class Association implements Serializable {
   /** Serial ID.*/
   @Serial
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -7206954677114644630L;

   /** Numéro Waldec national unique de l’association. */
   private NumeroWaldec numeroWaldec;
   
   /** Ancien numéro waldec. */
   private AncienNumeroWaldec ancienNumeroWaldec;
   
   /** Siret de l'association (facultatif). */
   private SIRET siret;
   
   /** Numéro d'association reconnue d'utilité publique (RUP) attribué par le Ministère. */
   private NumeroRUP numeroRUP;
   [...]

   /**
    * Construire une association.
    */
   public Association() {
   }

   /**
    * Construire une association.
    * @param numeroWaldec Numéro waldec de l'association.
    * @param ancienNumeroWaldec Ancien numéro waldec de l'association.
    * @param siret SIRET de l'association.
    * @param numeroRUP N° de RUP attribué par le Ministère.
    * [...]
    */
   public Association(String numeroWaldec, String ancienNumeroWaldec, String siret, String numeroRUP, String gestion,
         String nature, String groupement, String titre, String titreCourt, String objet, 
         String codeObjetSocial1, String codeObjetSocial2, String nomDeclarant, String civiliteDeclarant, String siteWeb, 
         String autorisationPublicationWeb, String observation, String positionActivite, Instant majTime, String libelleObjetSocial1, 
         String libelleObjetSocial2, String codeCommune, String nomCommune, String codeRegion, String codeDepartement, 
         String codeEPCI, String nomEPCI, Integer populationTotale, LocalDate dateCreation, LocalDate dateDerniereDeclaration,
         LocalDate datePublicationJOcreation, LocalDate dateDissolution, Double nombreAnneesExistence, Double nombreAnneesDerniereDeclaration, String adresseSiegeComplement, 
         String adresseSiegeNumeroVoie, String adresseSiegeTypeVoie, String adresseSiegeLibelleVoie, String adresseSiegeDistribution, 
         String adresseSiegeCodePostal, String adresseGestionComplementAssociation, String adresseGestionComplementGeo, String adresseGestionLibelleVoie, String adresseGestionDistributionFacturation, 
         String adresseGestionCodePostal, String adresseGestionAchemine, String adresseGestionPays) {
      this(numeroWaldec != null ? new NumeroWaldec(numeroWaldec) : null, 
         ancienNumeroWaldec != null ? new AncienNumeroWaldec(ancienNumeroWaldec) : null, 
         siret != null ? new SIRET(siret) : null, 
         numeroRUP != null ? new NumeroRUP(numeroRUP) : null, 
         gestion,
         
         nature,
         groupement != null ? Arrays.stream(RegroupementAssociation.values()).filter(e -> groupement.equals(e.getCode())).findFirst().get() : null,
         titre, 
         titreCourt, 
         objet, 
         
         codeObjetSocial1, 
         codeObjetSocial2,
         
         new Adresse(titreCourt, null, adresseSiegeComplement, adresseSiegeNumeroVoie, adresseSiegeTypeVoie,
               null, adresseSiegeLibelleVoie, adresseSiegeCodePostal, null, adresseSiegeDistribution, 
               null, codeCommune, nomCommune, null, null, null),
         
         nomDeclarant,
         
         new Adresse(adresseGestionComplementGeo, adresseGestionAchemine, adresseGestionComplementAssociation, null, null,
               null, adresseGestionLibelleVoie, adresseGestionCodePostal, null, adresseGestionDistributionFacturation, 
               null, null, null, null, adresseGestionPays, null),
         
         civiliteDeclarant, 
         siteWeb, 
         toBoolean(autorisationPublicationWeb), 
         observation, 
         positionActivite, 
         
         majTime, 
         libelleObjetSocial1, 
         libelleObjetSocial2,
         codeCommune != null ? new CodeCommune(codeCommune) : null, 
         nomCommune, 
         
         codeRegion != null ? new CodeRegion(codeRegion) : null, 
         codeDepartement != null ? new CodeDepartement(codeDepartement) : null, 
         codeEPCI != null ? new SIRET(codeEPCI) : null,
         nomEPCI, 
         populationTotale,
         
         dateCreation, 
         dateDerniereDeclaration, 
         datePublicationJOcreation, 
         dateDissolution, 
         nombreAnneesExistence, 
         nombreAnneesDerniereDeclaration);
   }
   
   /**
    * Construire une association.
    * @param numeroWaldec Numéro waldec de l'association.
    * @param ancienNumeroWaldec Ancien numéro waldec de l'association.
    * @param siret SIRET de l'association.
    * @param numeroRUP N° de RUP attribué par le Ministère.
    * [...]
    */
   public Association(NumeroWaldec numeroWaldec, AncienNumeroWaldec ancienNumeroWaldec, SIRET siret, NumeroRUP numeroRUP, String gestion, 
         String nature, RegroupementAssociation groupement, String titre, String titreCourt, String objet, 
         String codeObjetSocial1, String codeObjetSocial2, Adresse adresseSiege, String nomDeclarant, Adresse adresseGestion, 
         String civiliteDeclarant, String siteWeb, boolean autorisationPublicationWeb, String observation, String positionActivite, 
         Instant majTime, String libelleObjetSocial1, String libelleObjetSocial2, CodeCommune codeCommune, String nomCommune, 
         CodeRegion codeRegion, CodeDepartement codeDepartement, SIRET codeEPCI, String nomEPCI, Integer populationTotale, 
         LocalDate dateCreation, LocalDate dateDerniereDeclaration, LocalDate datePublicationJOcreation, LocalDate dateDissolution, Double nombreAnneesExistence, 
         Double nombreAnneesDerniereDeclaration) {
      this.numeroWaldec = numeroWaldec;
      this.ancienNumeroWaldec = ancienNumeroWaldec;
      this.siret = siret;
      this.numeroRUP = numeroRUP;
      [...]
   }
   
   /**
    * Renvoyer le numéro waldec de l'association.
    * @return Numéro waldec de l'association.
    */
   public NumeroWaldec getNumeroWaldec() {
      return this.numeroWaldec;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le numéro waldec de l'association.
    * @param numeroWaldec Numéro waldec de l'association.
    */
   public void setNumeroWaldec(NumeroWaldec numeroWaldec) {
      this.numeroWaldec = numeroWaldec;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer l'ancien numéro waldec de l'association.
    * @return Ancien numéro waldec de l'association.
    */
   public AncienNumeroWaldec getAncienNumeroWaldec() {
      return this.ancienNumeroWaldec;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer l'ancien numéro waldec de l'association.
    * @param ancienNumeroWaldec Ancien numéro waldec de l'association.
    */
   public void setAncienNumeroWaldec(AncienNumeroWaldec ancienNumeroWaldec) {
      this.ancienNumeroWaldec = ancienNumeroWaldec;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le siret de l'association.
    * @return SIRET.
    */
   public SIRET getSiret() {
      return this.siret;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le siret de l'association.
    * @param siret SIRET.
    */
   public void setSiret(SIRET siret) {
      this.siret = siret;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le numéro d'association reconnue d'utilité publique (RUP) attribué par le Ministère.
    * @return Numéro d'association reconnue d'utilité publique (RUP) attribué par le Ministère..
    */
   public NumeroRUP getNumeroRUP() {
      return this.numeroRUP;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le numéro d'association reconnue d'utilité publique (RUP) attribué par le Ministère.
    * @param numeroRUP Numéro d'association reconnue d'utilité publique (RUP) attribué par le Ministère.
    */
   public void setNumeroRUP(NumeroRUP numeroRUP) {
      this.numeroRUP = numeroRUP;
   }
[...]
}
```

I have a test, extracting a `Dataset<Association>` from a `Dataset<Row>`, that is working well. It has to use an `Encoders.bean(Association.class)` in a step of what it is doing:

```java
/**
 * Lecture d'associations, sous forme d'objets métiers.
 */
@Test
@DisplayName("Associations en objets métiers")
void associationObjetsMetiers() {
   Dataset<Row> rowAssociations = this.associationsDataset.rowAssociations(this.session, ANNEE_RNA, COG, true, AssociationWaldecTri.RNA_WALDEC, this.verifications)
      .limit(100);

   List<Association> associations = this.associationsDataset.toObjetsMetiersList(rowAssociations);
   assertNotEquals(0, associations.size(), "Un objet métier association au moins aurait du être obtenue");
}
```

where `associationsDataset.toObjetsMetiersList(rowAssociations)` goes through a piece of code:

```java
rows.map((MapFunction<Row, Association>)this::toObjetMetier, Encoders.bean(Association.class))
```

with:

```java
public Association toObjetMetier(Row r) {
   return new Association(r.getAs("numero_waldec"),
      r.getAs("ancien_numero_waldec"),
      r.getAs("siret"),
      r.getAs("numero_rup"),
      [...]
}
```

But I have also another simpler test, converting a single `Row` to an `Association`:

```java
/**
 * Lecture d'associations, sous forme d'objets métiers.
 */
@Test
@DisplayName("Row en objet métier")
void associationObjetMetier() {
   Row rowAssociation = this.associationsDataset.rowAssociations(this.session, ANNEE_RNA, COG, true, AssociationWaldecTri.RNA_WALDEC, this.verifications).first();

   assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
      Association association = this.associationsDataset.toObjetMetier(rowAssociation);
      LOGGER.info("Association lue  par conversion de Row en objet métier : {}", association);
      });
}
```

and it is working very well too!
...But it isn't using any encoder.

```
2023-05-04 09:22:25.665  INFO 42379 --- [           main] f.e.a.o.s.d.a.AssociationsDatasetIT      : Association lue  par conversion de Row en objet métier : fr.ecoemploi.domain.model.territoire.association.Association@3594aadb[adresseGestion=Adresse {nom : null, complément de nom : VILLENEUVE-DE-BERG, complément de voie : null, type de voie : null, numéro dans la voie : null, répétition dans la voie : null, voie : 238  RUE DU JARDIN PUBLIC, code postal : 07170, commune : null, commentaire : null, code commune: null, bureau distributeur : null, code cedex : null, libellé cedex : null, code pays étranger : null, nom pays étranger : FRANCE},adresseSiege=Adresse {nom : UNION REGIONALE DES FOYERS RURAUX R..., complément de nom : null, complément de voie : null, type de voie : RUE, numéro dans la voie : null, répétition dans la voie : 238, voie : du jardin public, code postal : 07170, commune : Villeneuve-de-Berg, commentaire : null, code commune: null, bureau distributeur : _, code cedex : null, libellé cedex : 07341, code pays étranger : null, nom pays étranger : null},ancienNumeroWaldec=0012006868,autorisationPublicationWeb=false,civiliteDeclarant=PM,codeCommune=07341,codeDepartement=07,codeEPCI=240700815,codeObjetSocial1=009035,codeObjetSocial2=023040,codeRegion=84,dateCreation=1986-07-11,dateDerniereDeclaration=2012-06-27,dateDissolution=1901-01-01,datePublicationJOcreation=1986-08-06,gestion=071S,groupement=SIMPLE,libelleObjetSocial1=Foyers ruraux,libelleObjetSocial2=Représentation d'intérêts économiques sectoriels,majTime=2012-06-27T13:23:30Z,nature=D,nomCommune=Villeneuve-de-Berg,nomDeclarant=<null>,nomEPCI=CC Berg et Coiron,nombreAnneesDerniereDeclaration=10.857534246575343,nombreAnneesExistence=36.83835616438356,numeroRUP=<null>,numeroWaldec=W012003219,objet=susciter et d'encourager la création de foyers ruraux et associations et de faciliter la constitution et le fonctionnement des fédérations départementales
 la solidarité entre ses membres
 un rôle d'information et de documentation
  procurer à ses membres la documentation et les renseignements de tous ordres dont ils peuvent avoir besoin et de mettre à leur disposition les moyens dont elle bénéficie
 servir de centre permanent de relations
 de réflexion et de recherche
 organiser la formation et le perfectionnement des animateurs professionnels et bénévoles du mouvement et plus généralement du milieu rural
 participer et contribuer de façon active et permanente à toute action favorisant le développement culturel, économique et social du milieu rural
 favoriser de développement en contribuant en particulier à la promotion des produits agricoles, des produits artisanaux et autres
 contribuer et s'engager dans toute action d'accueil et de tourisme social et rural,observation=Reprise  =>  date publication création au JO à vérifier date ag=0000-00-00,populationTotale=3097,positionActivite=A,siret=<null>,siteWeb=<null>,titre=UNION REGIONALE DES FOYERS RURAUX RHÔNE-ALPES  (U.R.F.R.  RHÔNE-ALPES),titreCourt=UNION REGIONALE DES FOYERS RURAUX R...,ejecter=false]
```

So I conclude that `Encoders.bean(Association.class)` isn't really necessary to the Spark map function, provided I'm creating myself the wished instance of each target business object with a `new` calling a constructor with all the properties of that business object.

Do I have a way to remove the `Encoders.bean(Association.class)` in the map function?